# Proof using closed graph theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Let $A:X\rightarrow X$ be a linear map such that $\forall \phi \in X' : \phi \circ A$ is continuous. Prove that $A$ is continuous. How can I prove it **using Closed Graph Theorem**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(x_n, A(x_n))$ be a sequence in the graph of $A$ that converges to $(x, y)$. By the closed graph theorem, it's sufficient to prove that $A(x) = y$.

Let $\phi \in X'$. Since $x_n \to x$ and $\phi \circ A$ is continuous, $$\phi(A(x_n)) = (\phi \circ A)(x_n) \to (\phi \circ A)(x) = \phi(A(x)).$$
Since $A(x_n) \to y$ and $\phi$ is continuous,$$\phi(A(x_n)) \to \phi(y).$$
We conclude that $\phi(A(x)) = \phi(y)$ for every $\phi \in X'$. This implies that $A(x) = y$ because $X'$ separates points.

Comment: Why and what does it mean that$X'$ separates points?

Comment: It means that for every $x \neq y$, there is a $\phi \in X'$ such that $\phi(x) \neq \phi(y)$. It can be proved using the Hahn-Banach separation theorem on the compact convex sets $\{x\}$ and $\{y\}$.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to not use this fact in the above proof?

Comment: You can use another equivalent fact, such as the fact that the weak topology is Hausdorff, but some form of the Hahn-Banach theorem is still needed to prove this.

Comment: weak topology is Hausdorff is a fact that we proved on our classes. thanks